# RNN sequence learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to TensorFlow RNN prediction. 
I am trying to use RNN with BasicLSTMCell to predict sequence, such as

```py
1,2,3,4,5 ->6
3,4,5,6,7 ->8
35,36,37,38,39 ->40
```

My code doesn't report error, but outputs for every batch seem to be the same, and the cost seem to not reduce while training.

When I divided all training data by 100

```py
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05 ->0.06
0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07 ->0.08 
0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39 ->0.40
```

The result is pretty good, the correlation between prediction and real values is very high (0.9998).

I suspect the problem is because integer and float? but I cannot explain the reason. Anyone can help? Many thanks!!

Here is the code

```py
library(tensorflow)
start=sample(1:1000, 100000, T)
start1= start+1
start2=start1+1
start3= start2+1
start4=start3+1
start5= start4+1
start6=start5+1
label=start6+1
data=data.frame(start, start1, start2, start3, start4, start5, start6, label)
data=as.matrix(data)
n = nrow(data)
trainIndex = sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace=FALSE)
train = data[trainIndex ,]
test = data[-trainIndex ,]
train_data= train[,1:7]
train_label= train[,8]
means=apply(train_data, 2, mean)
sds= apply(train_data, 2, sd)
train_data=(train_data-means)/sds
test_data=test[,1:7]
test_data=(test_data-means)/sds
test_label=test[,8]
batch_size = 50L            
n_inputs = 1L               # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_steps = 7L                # time steps
n_hidden_units = 10L        # neurons in hidden layer
n_outputs = 1L             # MNIST classes (0-9 digits)
x = tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL, n_steps, n_inputs))
y = tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL, 1L))
weights_in= tf$Variable(tf$random_normal(shape(n_inputs, n_hidden_units)))
weights_out= tf$Variable(tf$random_normal(shape(n_hidden_units, 1L)))
biases_in=tf$Variable(tf$constant(0.1, shape= shape(n_hidden_units )))
biases_out = tf$Variable(tf$constant(0.1, shape=shape(1L)))
RNN=function(X, weights_in, weights_out, biases_in, biases_out)
{
    X = tf$reshape(X, shape=shape(-1, n_inputs))
    X_in = tf$sigmoid (tf$matmul(X, weights_in) + biases_in)
    X_in = tf$reshape(X_in, shape=shape(-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units)
    lstm_cell = tf$contrib$rnn$BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=T)
    init_state = lstm_cell$zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf$float32)
    outputs_final_state = tf$nn$dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=F)
    outputs= tf$unstack(tf$transpose(outputs_final_state[[1]], shape(1,0,2)))
    results =  tf$matmul(outputs[[length(outputs)]], weights_out) + biases_out
    return(results)
}
pred = RNN(x, weights_in, weights_out, biases_in, biases_out)
cost = tf$losses$mean_squared_error(pred, y)
train_op = tf$contrib$layers$optimize_loss(loss=cost, global_step=tf$contrib$framework$get_global_step(), learning_rate=0.05, optimizer="SGD")
init <- tf$global_variables_initializer()
sess <- tf$Session()
sess.run(init)
    step = 0
while (step < 1000)
{
  train_data2= train_data[(step*batch_size+1) : (step*batch_size+batch_size) ,  ]
  train_label2=train_label[(step*batch_size+1):(step*batch_size+batch_size)]
  batch_xs <- sess$run(tf$reshape(train_data2, shape(batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs))) # Reshape
  batch_ys= matrix(train_label2, ncol=1)
  sess$run(train_op, feed_dict = dict(x = batch_xs, y= batch_ys))
 mycost <- sess$run(cost, feed_dict = dict(x = batch_xs, y= batch_ys))
print (mycost)
 test_data2= test_data[(0*batch_size+1) : (0*batch_size+batch_size) ,  ]
  test_label2=test_label[(0*batch_size+1):(0*batch_size+batch_size)]
   batch_xs <- sess$run(tf$reshape(test_data2, shape(batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs))) # Reshape
  batch_ys= matrix(test_label2, ncol=1)
step=step+1
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code? Without it it's hard to determine what might be the issue. Also it's not unthinkable to have such a high correlation if your dataset is so simple (is it still high if you introduce noise/errors in your dataset?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added the code, I am just testing the concept, so the dataset is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's quite useful to always normalize your network inputs (there are different approaches, divide by a maximum value, subtract mean and divide by std and many more). This will help your optimizer a lot.

Second, and actually most important in your case, after the RNN output you are applying sigmoid function. If you check the plot of the sigmoid function, you will see that it actually scales all inputs to the range (0,1). So basically no matter how big your inputs are your output will always be at most 1. Thus you should not use any activation functions at the output layer in regression problems.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi asakryukin, Thanks for your suggestions!! 
 I added the feature normalization and removed sigmoid activation function, however, seems these two changes didn't solve the problem. Results seem to be same. In fact, after learning, the preduction from each batch are pretty the same. For instance,
one batch, the real Ys are : 810, 284, 83.... 35 (50  values)
the predicted  ys are: 494.8970, 494.8970.....494.8970,494.8976 (50 values) 
The prediction are pretty close the mean of all real Y (i.e. 500), 
Don't know how to solve or explain

Comment: @user2146141 did you normalize both inputs and Ys? Try to normalize both and then scale back after the output...Because you still get input in (0,1) to the last layer, so when the net is trained last W is a fixed value. That's why the network just learns average of all Y's during the training, as it will minimize the error, otherwise it's not possible to get some W which will be multiplied by (0,1) number and result in 810 and 83 at the same time for different inputs